# How do you use iPad?

Tags: ipad

I've bought the device lately and I use it almost everyday for mail, calendars, web and such stuff. But I have a feeling that I haven't even scratched the surface.

Could you share your own ways of using it?

Do you use it for work?

Comment: As long as this is a CW why vote it down?!?!

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but it's a very wide ranging question, perhaps it would be useful to target it a bit more specifically. It's essentially an entire computing platform, potential uses are extensive.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I use mine:

1. Pages - create rough drafts for blog posts and gather ideas for future posts.  I've written whole term papers on the iPad.
2. Kindle App (awesome)
3. iBooks - pdf's and ebooks can be imported into it.  Great for doing research (see item 1).
4. I use several great stock market apps to do research.
5. Evernote (it's the best idea gathering tool)
6. Mindmapping, general brainstorming and flow charts with Penultimate and Adobe Ideas.
7. Twitter
8. RSS Reader
9. Import photos from my DSLR for viewing and quick fixes (PS Mobile).
10. Watch college lectures.

I could probably keep going.  The iPad has become an essential device for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use it mainly to read my rss feeds in the morning. It has pretty much replaced my laptop in the lounge at night, while the desktop still remains for serious processing power when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the memo about the iPad only being for 'consumption'. I do a lot of painting on my iPad...

http://www.flickr.com/photos/acute-distress/sets/72157622067589687/

Comment: +1 Great pictures! What apps do you use to 'paint'?

Answer (score 1):

With [log me in](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/ios/?WT.mc_id=8147&utpk=log%20me%20in%20iPad&campaign=us&destination=/welcome/iphone/&originid=56816) for iPad, I can control my Mac/PC remotely so that I don't need to carry my Macbook pro anymore at a meeting.

With [GPS drive motion X](http://news.motionx.com/category/motionx-gps-drive/), I have a cool GPS, so I don't need a TomTom anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am a financial blogger, but wrote an article about [Evernote on the iPad](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/evernote-ipad-revisited/). The article addresses how to use "Bookmarklets" on the iPad. These are little Java scripts that can let you clip a page to Evernote (one of the killer iPad apps) save a bookmark to deli.cio.us or other. Between these two apps, when I am away from home and surfing on the iPad, it's easy to save items for further review.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I've used exclusively my iPad at work.  I checked emails, made some transactions on the Web-based ERP, used the VPN and called with my Cisco Mobile Phone on the iPad, and attended a Webex meeting.

The battery lasted for the whole workday.

Answer (score -5):

The iPad is just an entertainment device.  It's good for viewing movies, checking email, playing games, but for not for real functionality that work would require.

The meaty part of the device you haven't scratched yet are the millions of apps available.

Generally though, laptops are for work, and iPads are for entertainment.

Comment: That really depends on the kind of work you do. If you *must* use Xcode, AutoCAD or Photoshop, then of course you need a laptop/desktop. But I know a lot of people (writers, musicians, painters) who get real work done on the iPad, with much greater efficiency than a laptop/desktop.

Comment: What an incredibly short-sighted answer. There are many, MANY different ways that "real work" can be done on an iPad.

Comment: I agree, you are way underselling your iPad, I work in IT, and also do the comp. webpage... I use my iPad for everything anymore, infact I find that I only use my laptop anymore for working on the said webpage, and if my iPad runs out of batter (which never happens) it is "a great piece of technology" as said by my boss, and a great tool. If you are only using it for entertainment, then you are not using it to its fullest potential.

Comment: @Can You will be able to take Photoshop off of your list sometime soon: http://www.tuaw.com/2011/04/01/adobe-demos-photoshop-on-the-ipad?icid=sphere_aol_tuaw